# Why I am getting below warning and can not excute this procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

[image: SQL]

I am running this in SQL DEVELOPER but it's compiling with warning and also while executing saying invalid command

```
create or replace procedure testproc as 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TEST
WHERE c1 = 'A';
END;
```

Comment: Any time you ask about a warning or error, please include the text of the warning or error in your question. We can't see screen shots or the contents of links on the site. The SO search can't find them. If the link changes your question will no longer make any sense.

Comment: See what the actual error is (you can use `show errors`, or query the `user_errors` view - though to use either in the same worksheet you will have to put a `/` after that block); but in a PL/SQL context you have to select *into* something.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare a variable in Plsql every time you are selecting a value.. Here I have used `%ROWTYPE` to fetch the entire row in to variable `test_var` However it depends on your requirement what you want to do.
check the  [snippet](http://psoug.org/snippet/Oracle-PL-SQL-TYPE-vs-ROWTYPE--Whats-the-difference_700.htm) and you will get the idea..

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE testproc
    AS
      test_var test%rowtype;
    BEGIN
      SELECT * INTO test_var FROM TEST WHERE c1 = 'A';
    END;
    /
```